# Why does the filename requested from the server start with Unicode characters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, ftp

I use FTP to list the file attributes on the server. I request the name of file and put them into an array. I print the array directly like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

What I got is like this:

```
\U6587\U4ef6\U540d\Uff1afilename.txt
\U6587\U4ef6\U540d\Uff1afilename1.txt
......
```

When I want to print the Unicode "\U6587\U4ef6\U540d\Uff1a" to see what it is, I got the compiling error: "incomplete universal character name".

However, If I print the name instead of the whole array, I can get the name correctly without the Unicode. But I need to do something with the name in the array. I want to know why the Unicode is there, and is it proper to just remove the Unicode then to do something with the real file name?

Comment: Some collection classes, when they generate their description, add quoting and/or escaping to strings which are not "simple" for some definition of "simple". Pure ASCII, at least, plus often having any characters other than Latin letters and digits. This **does not** mean that the strings themselves contain those escape sequences or quotes. It's just how the collection formatted its contents into a description string. Basically, ignore it and just use the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C99, and therefore presumably Objective C too, there are two Unicode escapes:

```
\uXXXX
\UXXXXXXXX
```

The lower-case `u` is followed by 4 hex digits; the upper-case `U` is followed by 8 hex digits (of which, the first two should be zeroes to be valid Unicode (and the third should be 0 or 1; the maximum Unicode code point is U+10FFFF).

I believe that if you replace the upper-case `U`'s with lower-case `u`'s, you should get the code to compile.

On my Mac OS 10.7.4 system, compiling with GCC 4.7.0 (home built), I compiled this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char array[] = "\u6587\u4ef6\u540d\uff1a";
    puts(array);
    return 0;
}
```

and got this output:

- 文件名：

I can't answer why the characters are there, but the colon-like character at the end suggests that the site might be preceding the actual file name with a tag of some sort (analogous to 'file:').

Comment: For completeness, `文件名：` means `Filename:`

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelRobinson.  Sometimes, I get lucky!  The first three characters are from the CJK Unified Ideographs (U+4E00..U+9FCF), and the last is a FULL WIDTH COLON.

Comment: no problem! Chinese use full width punctuation, which looks horrible IMHO: `。-/（）——；‘’：`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Jonathan said, you might have to use `stringWithUTF8String:`, but I agree that the error is with the capital `U` rather than `u`.